# Collect checkboxes values (dynamically created) using Angular 6

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular6

I'm newbie on the Angular and I apologize if it's a dummy question, but anyway.

I have the following structure in Angular 6:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (submit)="doStuff()">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Select</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users; index as i">
      <th>{{i+1}}</th>
      <td>{{user?.key}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="form.controls['selectedUsersGroup'].controls[i]"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><button type="submit">Do</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically I have a list of users, which my service returns and I want to get keys of only selected on the form users (clicked on the checkboxes).

In my component I created form and array of false values, associated with checkboxes (as no users are selected by default):

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.usersSelected = new Array(10).fill(false);
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedUsersGroup: this.formBuilder.array(this.usersSelected)
  });
}
```

The interesting part is when I have to get keys of selected users. 
When clicked on submit button the following method is called:

```
doStuff() {

   //get checkboxes group
   this.usersSelected= this.form.get('selectedUsersGroup').value;

   //get indexes of selected checkboxes
   var indexes = [];
   var idx = this.usersSelected.indexOf(true);
   while (idx != -1) {
     indexes.push(idx);
     idx = this.usersSelected.indexOf(true, idx + 1);
   }

   //get keys of users by indexes of selected checkboxes
   var keys = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
     keys.push(this.users[indexes[i]].key);
   }
 }
```

This is working fine, but it looks too heavy, I'm pretty sure there is a more simple and elegant solution.

I would be glad if someone could point me on that)

Comment: try iterating over formControls instead of formControl's value. something like this line: `(this.form.get('selectedUsersGroup')! as FormArray).controls.reduce((keys, formControl, formControlIndeyIndex) => formControl.value ? [...keys, this.users[formControlIndeyIndex]]: keys , new Array<any>());`

Comment: @A.Winnen thanks, it works fine! Could you please explain what does it actually do?

Comment: the statement just uses standard javascript/typescript functions. No magic involved. since i cannot explain it better than mozilla, just refer to:
[Spread-Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) 
[Array-Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: @A.Winnen thanks a ton!